# Laptop speakers stop working after a time, work again after inserting and removing headset

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, speakers

I have a very weird problem. Toshiba laptop, running windows 7. So I can put on a youtube video and it works for a while, after a few minutes, the audio stops playing through the speakers...its playing one minute and then complete silence the next. The video is still playing and no sounds will work (clicking the speaker icon to "ding" or any other video at this point). Now here is the weird part...if I plug in a headset or speakers into the speaker jack, I can hear the audio through the headset or speakers. Then if we unplug it, the speakers start playing again. I can replicate this issue exactly over and over. The audio usually takes anywhere from a minute to three minutes to stop. We have already completely uninstalled the audio driver and re installed(latest driver from toshiba based on this exact model).

I think it might have to do with faulty headset detection. The audio jack has been cleaned and dusted.

Any thoughts?

Comment: An interesting development for this. The laptop has a headphone jack and a separate mic jack. Once the audio quits, plugging something into the mic jack immediately makes the sound come back as well.

Comment: Try a very old driver to see if that makes a change.

Comment: The laptop is only a few years old, so there is no "very old" drivers available. There is one single driver available from toshiba.

Comment: Toshiba laptops are crap and they use crappy parts. Is it possible you have a defective headphone jack? You could try using a rubber band or something to keep the audio jack in a position that keeps the connection active. Or fuhgetaboutit and use the speaker jack going forward. Or you could use a USB to audio to eliminate either audio jacks as a transmission source.

Comment: my Dell workstation does this some times, it is most likely related to the driver of the audio device

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answered your own question.
It'll probably a faulty headset detection problem. Because your sound returns after inserting a headset...
If you cleaned everything out, there are not that many options left. Probably the jacket isn't properly connected anymore to your main board. Reasons for this could be bad soldering or heavy use of the jacket...

Options:

- open up your laptop to check if this is the case. Try to solder it.
- disable your sound card device in device manager and buy an external use sound card  to replace it